# How to display a message in JPanel from DATABASE?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-7

I'm making a java Project that going to display a Request "something :)" from database..

I've done making a database and a request form.

My problem is I don't have an idea how to display the message on my JPANEL.

Here's the code.

```
try{    
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webservice","root","");

   String sql="Insert into request(PurposeofTrip,DestinationS,VehicleModel,RequestingDept,DriverName,OvernightUse) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";


   pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

   pst.setString(1, txt_trip.getText());
   pst.setString(2, txt_dest.getText());

   String value=combo_model.getSelectedItem().toString();
   pst.setString(3, value);
   pst.setString(4, txt_requ.getText());
   pst.setString(5, txt_dname.getText());
   String value2=combo_night.getSelectedItem().toString();
   pst.setString(6, value2);

   pst.execute();                

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Request Send");
}catch(Exception e){
    ...
}
```

How to display a message in JPanel from DATABASE?

Comment: "how to display it on my JPANEL", What is "it"?

Comment: This is a very incomplete question. Please tell us what sort of information you're extracting from the database, how you want it displayed, etc. Please don't assume that we can read minds or see code not shown.

Comment: I have deleted the [tag:javascript] tag from your question and have added the [tag:swing] tag. You will want to read up on and learn the differences between these two programming languages because there are many.

Comment: what im trying to say is that......
uhhmmm i want to do such kind of a inbox..something like that...
inbox of request..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're inserting into the database, it looks like you want to show the status of the insertion. What I would do is just use a `JLabel`. No need for a `JPanel` in a `JPanel` you need to actually paint the message yourself. You can do something like this. Keep in mind that `.excuteUpdate()` return an `int` which is the number of rows affected.

```
int result = pst.executeUpdate();
if (result == 0) {
    statusLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
    statusLabel.setText("Error Inserting record");
} else {
    statusLabel.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    statusLabel.setText("Insert Successful");
}
```

`statusLabel` being a `JLabel` that you have added somewhere to your GUI previously

Comment: yes something like that..
im sorry guys..
im new in the programming world.. T__T